# Op Amp magnitude of gain proof

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain

I've been working through a proof but I'm stuck on one of the last steps. Consider an inverting op amp with a feedback resistor \$R_f\$ in series with a capacitor and resistor \$R_1\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGDTdB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I must prove that: $$ \frac {|V_o|}{|V_i|} = \frac {R_f}{R_1} \frac {1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{f_1^2}{f^2}}} $$

My steps so far:
$$ \frac {V_o}{V_i} = \frac {R_f}{R_1 - \frac {j}{\omega C}}$$
$$   = \frac {1}{\frac{R_1}{R_f} - \frac{j}{\omega RC}} $$
$$=\frac{1}{\frac{R_1}{R_f}-j\frac{\omega_c}{\omega}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\frac{R_1}{R_f}-j\frac{f_c}{f}}$$
Now, how would I go about bringing the resistances out? (a little rusty on my algebra haha)

Thanks!

Comment: You can add a schematic using the editor (shortcut: ctrl+M). It's really unclear what circuit you are trying to solve.

Comment: You have absolute values on the left in the equation to prove. Try ((...)^2)^1/2 on you last step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Bringing the resistances out

Starting from your final equation,
$$\frac{V_o}{V_i} = \frac{1}{\frac{R_1}{R_f}-j\frac{f_c}{f}}\tag{1}$$
 where \$f_c =\dfrac{1}{2\pi R_f C}\$.

Let \$f_1 = \dfrac{1}{2\pi R_1 C}\$ then,
$$f_c = \frac{R_1}{R_f}\times f_1$$ Applying this in \$(1)\$,
$$\frac{V_o}{V_i} = \frac{1}{\frac{R_1}{R_f}-j\frac{f_1}{f}\times \frac{R_1}{R_f}}$$
$$\left|\frac{V_o}{V_i}\right| = \left|\frac{R_f}{R_1}\times\frac{1}{1-j\frac{f_1}{f}}\right|$$
$$= \frac{R_f}{R_1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{f_1^2}{f^2}}}$$

---

> Alternate method

You should have started this way. Especially when you had the final answer with you. :)

$$ \frac {V_o}{V_i} = \frac {R_f}{R_1 - \frac {j}{\omega C}}$$
$$= \frac{R_f}{R_1}\frac{1}{1-j\frac{1}{\omega R_1 C}}$$
$$= \frac{R_f}{R_1}\frac{1}{1-j\frac{f_1}{f}}$$

Taking absolute value results in the required result.